# What's a significant slogan for the formal review process?

Tags: review

*I hope this is the right QA site to ask this question, if not, please give me a hint, where to ask it :-)*

In my study (computer science) we got a module named "Software Quality", where the focus is set on different methods about testing processes.

I have the task to create a presentation about the formal review process (walkthrough, inspection, ...), its roles, benefits, and so on.

**I'm looking for** a significant/creative slogan that fits to the term "Review" or "Review process", like "Java is not an island" is a slogan to the programming language "Java".

So, be creative and help me please.

Comment: If this is found to be inappropriate for this forum, you can also try submitting it as a discussion at www.softwaretestingclub.com. A lot of creative, twisted minds running around there. :)

Comment: I think this is probably too subjective for this forum. It would certainly fit in over at the Software Testing Club forums.

Comment: From Dantes' Inferno: "Abandon hope all ye who enter here"

Comment: I started a discussion on www.softwaretestingclub.com. Hope to get a feedback there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic one might be the [Linus's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_Law): "given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow"

Answer (score 2):

How about: "If a job's worth doing it's worth doing well!"

Why do we review other peoples work, because they are sloppy? No, I believe in continuously improving in small steps, someone has to monitor what needs improving though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try these if it helps:

"Review or Lament"
"Review or Perish"